# Removing multiple items from ArrayList, shifting indexes

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList that I loop and through some logic I would remove an element at a particular index.

However while I am looping the Arraylist and removing on the way, the ArrayList size and index of particular items are changing as well, resulting in unexpected results.

Anyway to circumvent this?

Comment: You are probably getting a `ConcurrentModificationException`. That is what using a `Iterator` is all about. Also, consider using a `LinkedList` instead of an `ArrayList` if you are going to be regularly removing elements from the middle of the list.

Comment: FYI, next time your question would be clearer if you said what the "unexpected results" were. i.e. "I am getting a ConcurrentModificationException"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the code for the iterator approach - substitute your own condition and add generics types <> as needed:

```
Iterator it = list.iterator(); 
while(it.hasNext()){
    Object o = it.next();
    if(someCondition(o)){
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

And, as JohnB said in the comments, ArrayList isn't very efficient if you are removing lots of items from large lists...

Answer (score 4):

You can use an Iterator.remove() or iterate backwards.

```
List<String> list = ...
for(int i= list.size()-1; i>=0; i--)
   if(test(list.get(i)))
      list.remove(i); // values before `i` are untouched.
```

or you can decrement the counter.

```
List<String> list = ...
for(int i= 0; i < list.size(); i++)
   if(test(list.get(i)))
      list.remove(i--); // move i back as there is one less element.
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use an iterator which has a remove() method to do exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Iterator` for looping. It can be used to remove the elements from the collection.